# IS: Custom properties in SAML authentication response

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've created custom user store manager and now I'd like to get some claim properties in the authentication response message. How can I configure wso2 to attach these properties?

I've defined my claim and set it in the service provider claim definition, but I don't see it in the response. Are there any additional settings?

thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can Enable Attribute Profile and enable 'Include Attributes in the Response Always', at service provider configuration, if you want these claims to be added in all the responses.

Please refer the attached image.[image]

Thanks,
Pushpalanka